# Updating a JSON file with Wordpress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert a new object in a `JSON` file that is placed in my WP theme root, by using `wp_remote_post` command. The page does not throw any visible errors, but the `JSON` file is not getting updated either. I prefer this method instead of `file_put_contents` function so please help me understand this approach. Thanks.

**front-page.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['save']) && !empty($_POST['specie_name']) && !empty($_POST['specie_rate'])):

    $specie_name= $_POST['specie_name'];
    $specie_rate=(int)$_POST['specie_rate'];


    $url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/species.json';
       
    $body = wp_json_encode(array(
        'specie' => $specie_name,
        'rate' => $specie_rate,
    )); 
    
       $args = array(
    'body'        => $body,
    'headers'     => [  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',  ],
    'timeout'     => 60,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'blocking'    => true,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'sslverify'   => false,
    'data_format' => 'body',
     );
    
    wp_remote_post( $url, $args );

    endif;
```

**The JSON looks like this:**

```
[
    {
        "specie": "Oscar",
        "rate": 300
    },
    {
        "specie": "Piranha",
        "rate": 400
    },
]
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it appears that you are trying to make an unauthenticated HTTP POST to a URL, and are expecting a file at that URL to change. If I'm missing something, I apologize. But if I'm right, the entire internet would break if such a thing were possible. If the file system is yours, `file_put_contents` or similar is the most optimal way to do this. WordPress has wrappers for these, too. If you want to use HTTP, then you will need an API, or you'll need to manually configure "something".

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you for the insight. I had this impression because since I was able to get contents of the local JSON file through `wp_remote_get`, then `wp_remote_post` might work on it as well. Could you please briefly inform me about these Wordpress 'wrappers' for this purpose? Because that would be plain HTML wrappers if I'm not wrong. Just curious how is it connected here?

Comment: WordPress has a file system abstraction, you can see a simple version [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160919) and the full docs [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API). Personally I never use it because if I need FS access, I control the system and this doesn’t offer me any additional features.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. It looks overly complicated to me. I'll stick with file_put_contents :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this question as I believe I have figured the answer. That is, to get the `json` contents with `wp_remote_get`, and then using `file_put_contents` to push in data.